# How to avoid white screen in a webview when I press the back button on Android?

Tags: java, android

If I press the back button in my application, it shows a white screen. If  I press it again, it shows my activity. How can I remove the white screen Activity?

This my Activity:

```
public class Facebook extends AppCompatActivity
{

   WebView fb_link;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_facebook);

       fb_link = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fb);

       fb_link.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

       fb_link.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/profile.php id=100012806950302");

       fb_link.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

       fb_link.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

       fb_link.getSettings().getBuiltInZoomControls();

       fb_link.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

       fb_link.setInitialScale(1);

       fb_link.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

       fb_link.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

       fb_link.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

       fb_link.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

       fb_link.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

   }

   public void onBackPressed()
   {

       if(fb_link!=null && fb_link.canGoBack())
           fb_link.goBack();// if there is previous page open it
       else
           super.onBackPressed();//if there is no previous page, close app
   }

}
```

Comment: if i am pressing back button first time it will show white screen... again i am pressing back button my previous activity will be open... how to avoid the white screen ???

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer... try manifests in your web view activity
android:onHistory="true"